# Generate Kaminari semantic-ui theme

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, kaminari, pagination, semantic-ui

When I generate semantic-ui theme, this error occures. What to do with it?

```
rails g kaminari:views semantic-ui
no such theme: semantic_ui
avaliable themes: bootstrap2, bootstrap3, foundation, github, google, purecss, semantic-ui
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the generator does is copy the files of the theme into `app/views/kaminari/`. As a workaround you can just copy them from the master branch yourself from [here](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari_themes/tree/master/semantic_ui/app/views/kaminari)

Just get the zip-file of the repo from [here](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari_themes/archive/master.zip) and extract the `semantic-ui/app/views/kaminari/`folder contents into your app `app/views/kaminari/` (create the kaminari folder if you don't have it yet).

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147531/how-mark-my-question-as-answered-on-stackoverflow